# How to return reference to unique_ptr containing nullptr

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

Here is my code:

```
typedef map<string, unique_ptr<MyClass> > DB;

const unique_ptr<MyClass>>& find_it(const string &key, const DB &db)
{
  auto itr = db.find(key);
  if (itr == db.end()) {
    return nullptr;
  }
  return itr->second;
}
```

That return statement causes a compiler warning: `returning reference to local temporary object [-Wreturn-stack-address].`

Yes, I can understand that returning a reference to local temp variable is bad, but I wonder what is the simplest fix here given the following:

```
1. Do not expose the map to the callers of find_it (I use typedef here is just for asking this question, in real code it is wrapped inside an interface).
2. Using an iterator kind of thing to indicate the position of the searched item is a hassle to me, I like to avoid it.
```

Given these, the best I can come up is to break find_it() to 2 functions:

```
bool exists(const string &key, const DB &db)
{
  auto itr = db.find(key);
  return itr != db.end();
}

const unique_ptr<MyClass>>& find_it(const string &key, const DB &db)
{
  auto itr = db.find(key);
  assert(itr != db.end());
  return itr->second;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can't return reference to `nullptr` the same way you can't return an `int&` reference to `0`. Also, I don't understand how returning iterators is a hassle - you have to dereference the pointer anyway. What you should probably use instead is returning `boost::optional<MyClass&>` (or use other `optional` class, maybe one written by yourself) if user shouldn't care about `unique_ptr`s (and 99% of the case, he shouldn't - it's an implementation detail).

Comment: returning a reference to a `unique_ptr` could be considered misleading. I'd think returning a raw pointer, or a `shared_ptr` would be better. but returning an iterator object would be better than both of those.

Comment: Why not just take the parameters as iterators, return an iterator to the position on success and `db.end()` on failure?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `return nullptr` statement is implicitly constructing a `unique_ptr<MyClass>` instance and you're then returning a reference to it, hence the warning. A simple fix is to define a `static` `unique_ptr<MyClass>` that holds `nullptr` and return a reference to that instead.

```
const unique_ptr<MyClass>& find_it(const string &key, const DB &db)
{
  static unique_ptr<MyClass> not_found;

  auto itr = db.find(key);
  if (itr == db.end()) {
    return not_found;
  }
  return itr->second;
}
```

A better fix might be to use [`boost::optional`](http://www.boost.org/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html). Change the return type to `boost::optional<std::unique_ptr<MyClass>> const&`, and then return `boost::none` if the object is not found.

Comment: So we should initialize not_found to nullptr, is that right?

Comment: @my_question The [default constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr) will do that for you. You can construct it with a `nullptr` argument if you want to be more explicit about what you're doing.